# How to execute shell command using subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess

I need to execute a shell command that extracts mp3 file from the youtube url using youtube-dl

```
youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 -o '/var/www/html/ytrip/audio/%(id)s.%(ext)s'
```

Executing this line on the terminal, the mp3 file is generated and stored in `var/www/html/ytrip/audio/BaW_jenozKc.mp3`.

Now this is implemented on flask:

```
# flaskapp.py
# This is a "hello world" app sample for flask app. You may have a different file.
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import subprocess
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='', 
            static_folder='web/static',
            template_folder='web/templates')
@app.route('/') 
def index():
   return render_template("index.html") 
@app.route('/audios', methods=['POST', 'GET']) 
def audios():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      subprocess.call(['youtube-dl', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 -o /var/www/html/ytrip/audio/%(id)s.%(ext)s'])
   return render_template("audios.html") 

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```

This does not throw any error or the mp3 file is not extracted. Not sure how to use `subproces.call()`...

Tried with `subprocess.run()` too, but no luck

Comment: Use `subprocess.run(args, shell=True)` and split the list of args at every space in your command.

Comment: @crissal If you use `shell=True` then it should be a single string, not a list.

Comment: But in this case there's no need for `shell=True`, since it's not using any shell syntax.

Comment: @crissal, only the first list element gets split that way, not the subsequent ones. (What actually happens is that the first element is interpreted by the shell as a script to run, and subsequent elements become arguments to that script, so they can be referred to with `$0`, `$1`, etc. from within the script argument; that way you can safely pass arbitrary strings to your script without needing them to be escaped to be safe when substituted into code, which is otherwise mandatory to avoid introducing security bugs).

Comment: @crissal, ...anyhow, because improper use of `shell=True` _does_ cause security bugs, it's much better to tell folks how to avoid needing it than to tell them to use shells everywhere.

Comment: `run` will work if you use it like the following, note that flags & args are all split: `subprocess.run([shutil.which('youtube-dl'),  'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc', '--extract-audio', '--audio-format', 'mp3', '-o' '/var/www/html/ytrip/audio/%(id)s.%(ext)s']`

Comment: Thank you all. The actual issue was the folder permission. When set to 777, the mp3 file was saved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each argument to the command must be a separate list element.

```
subprocess.call([
  'youtube-dl',
  'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc',
  '--extract-audio',
  '--audio-format', 'mp3',
  '-o', '/var/www/html/ytrip/audio/%(id)s.%(ext)s'
])
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The actual issue was folder permission. When I set to 777 to project root folder, it worked.